# PowerMockito: @PrepareForTest programaticcaly?

Tags: annotations, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I am looking for a way to replace the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = ["jenkins.model.Jenkins", "hudson.model.Node", "hudson.model.Computer"])
class ClassToTest { ... }
```

By code that I would put in a setup method

```
@Before
void setup() {}
```

In the same way that it is possible to replace `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` by `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`

I need this because this annotation prevent me from using `@RunWith(Parametrized.class)` from Junit4

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using the [agent](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent)?

Comment: This is nice ! I am going to try this, thanks

Comment: It seems it is not working well with Groovy, I have this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clear JavaAgentClassRegister. Set method has not been called.

Comment: Maybe its the same issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468657/how-to-fix-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-clear-javaagentclassregister). What `jdk` version\vendor are you using?

Comment: I will have to check to make sure but I think it is JDK 8